# Pine Script history gap

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How come this script showing a gap between the 50th and the 201 bar? Does it have something to do with `max_bars_back`?

```
// © mickes

//@version=5
indicator("History", overlay = true)

for i = 1 to 200
    label.new(bar_index - i, high[i], text = str.tostring(i))
```

https://www.tradingview.com/x/cVe3yga5/
https://www.tradingview.com/x/EOyvAMCn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to the maximum amount of labels on the chart allowed by the script, you can control it with **max_labels_count=** parameter, default value is 50 - maximum is 500. Increase the value of the parameter to 200 to fix the issue:

```
//@version=5
indicator("History", overlay = true, max_labels_count = 200)

for i = 1 to 200
    label.new(bar_index - i, high[i], text = str.tostring(i))
```